# Azure AD app Need admin approval error: App needs permission to access resources in your organization that only an admin can grant

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We have an Azure AD app used for authenticating to APIs. We use permissions like offline_access, openid, profile, User.Read etc. and have granted admin consent already. This has been working since 1 year without any issues. In this week, we received 4-5 external users complaining about the error:

> Need admin approval
>
> App needs permission to access resources in your organization that
> only an admin can grant. Please ask an admin to grant permission to
> this app before you can use it.

1. It is not related to a particular external user from a particular organization, some other user from the same organization don't get this error.
2. This error occurs only for new external users, we haven't yet received any issues from existing external users.
3. Admin granted admin consent again after reported error but the users still get the same error message.

I went through few other questions with same error. But since the configuration has been working since past year I am bit confused. During this period we have had lot of external users without any issue.

What configuration should I check to resolve this? Or is there any update in Azure AD default settings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- **Check if the Allow users to consent to apps accessing company data on
  their behalf is set to No in Enterprise Application Users settings.**

  If it set to No then please toggle it to yes . This option lets users
  decide by themselves if they want to grant access to a given app to
  everyone in their organization.

> **From Microsoft’s official    documentation:** If this option is
> set to yes, then users may consent    to allow applications which are
> not published by Microsoft to access    your organization’s data, if
> the user also has access to the data.    This also means that the
> users will see these apps on their Access    Panels.  If this option
> is set to no, then admins must consent to    these applications before
> users may use them.

- **Check if the Allow users to request admin consent to apps they are
  unable to consent to is set to No.**

  If it is set to No then toggle it
  to yes as well. If your organization decides that users indeed must
  have explicit approval, this option makes it easy for those users to
  request approval.

  To enable this option, click on User settings (same
  as in the previous stem) and then toggle Admin consent requests to
  “Yes”. Make sure to Save your changes, which may take a few minutes
  to propagate.

> **From Microsoft Documentation:** If this option is set to    yes,
> then users request admin consent to any app that requires access    to
> data they do not have the permission to grant. If this option is
> set to no, then users must contact their admin to request to consent
> in order to use the apps they need.

[image]

> **Note :** If this Setting is done from your APP tenant , Please also check the **external users tenant** as this needs to be done from their
> side as well as while trying to use the app, your app will retrieve
> user profile etc. from the users tenant .

- **Add Priority Matrix as an Enterprise Application (org-wide)**

  if your
  AAD administrator decides that everyone in your organization should
  get access to Priority Matrix, they can follow these steps:

  From the
  “Enterprise Applications” view, click on All Applications

  Select +
  New Application to set up Priority Matrix with Azure AD
  authentication

  Search “Priority Matrix” and proceed to configure the
  app with AD authentication

[image]

> **Note:** If you still face the issue please reach out to Azure support engineer to get assisted support by clicking on (Help+support)
> and creating a technical support request as it may need live troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me understand. Users were not set to provide consent. We had to add Graph related permission which was not present when we debugged. After adding the missing permission followed by admin grant solved this issue.

Comment: @SushrutParanjape what was the missing permission? We have hit a similar issue

Comment: @sjgp In our case, we were adding scope Sites.ReadWrite.All in the login URL. But this app permission was missing in the Graph App (Sites.ReadWrite.All was present but someone might have removed this later). So even with admin providing consent, users were getting error. After adding Sites.ReadWrite.All again and providing admin consent, the error resolved for us. So you can check if you are requesting a specific permission but that is not added to the graph. I hope this helps.

Comment: also need admin role for the user, otherwise cannot proceed too

Comment: Why does it prompt for approval when admin has already approved?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that, Consent phishing attacks are highly emerging these days. So, as an admin, we should think about granting permissions to users consent to other applications into our Office 365. You can refer the blog [manage user consent to apps](https://blog.admindroid.com/manage-user-consent-to-applications-in-microsoft-365/) to know the ways to approve the applications that users requested.

Also, please don't get upset about the existing applications that were approved by user without your concern. You can now [review the permissions granted to apps in office 365](https://blog.admindroid.com/review-app-permissions-consents-in-microsoft-365/) and take remediations immediately if you find an unnecessary application.