# Xamarin Azure AD Authentication Need Admin Permission

Tags: azure, authentication, xamarin, azure-active-directory

Does anyone knows how to fix this, on my case no problem with login however, there are users who can't log in need admin permissions we are in the same tenant.

[this is the screenshot of login needs admin approval](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBP21.png)

Comment: please do not post code or errors as images - take the time to paste and format the exact error message in your post.  10 seconds of googling turns up this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/application-consent-experience

Comment: Please refer to this thread link for reference: - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68558357/azure-ad-app-need-admin-approval-error-app-needs-permission-to-access-resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the Xamarin app without admin consent because you have the admin consent enabled for you or you may be the administrator for that application/tenant. Thus, for the other users in your tenant to allow access to the Xamarin application, please follow the steps below: -

Go to your Azure AD --> Enterprise Applications --> User settings --> Admin consent requests --> Users can request admin consent to apps they are unable to consent to --> Yes
Then under the section ‘Who can review admin consent requests’, select the users and groups who can review the admin consent for the application (you can select the users themselves if you want them to access without actual/designated admin consent) and set the number of days for which the consent would remain valid and then it expires. Thus, this will ensure that users in your tenant will not receive the admin consent prompt while accessing the application.

Also, ensure that the option ‘Allow user consent for apps’ in User consent settings in Consent and permissions section in Enterprise Applications is selected for admin consent to permanently remove for all applications in your tenant. Please find the below screenshots for your reference: -

[image: Enterprise Applications user settings]
[image: Consent and Permissions]

Comment: hi @KartikBhiwapurkar-MT apologies for the late feedback just got back our electricity we experienced a strong typhoon here power was out, thank you for helping me. :)