# Admin Consent for users

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have an Enterprise Application which requires pretty nominal permissions:
[image: Enterprise App Permissions]

I have already granted consent as an admin.

When a user tries to access the app and logs-in they get this message:
[image: Need admin approval]

"needs permission to access resources in your organization that only an admin can grant. Please ask an admin to grant permission to this app before you can use it."

I don't want my users to see this message (they will call helpdesk or do the wrong thing).

I think the admin consent I provided above should be sufficient, so my questions are:

1. Is is possible to consent on behalf of the users
2. What settings to I need to change?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is nor related to programming

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent) ?

Comment: Following @Vega suggestion please move your question to [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/products/azure?product=identity).

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, it is possible to consent on behalf of the users. To achieve the same you must have `Global Administrator` or `Privileged Administrator` role.**

*Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> Enterprise applications -> Consent and permissions - > User consent settings*

[image]

**Check if the below option is set to No in Enterprise Application Users settings:**

[image]

**References:**

[Grant tenant-wide admin consent to an application - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent)

[Azure AD app Need admin approval error: App needs permission to access resources in your organization that only an admin can grant - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68558357/azure-ad-app-need-admin-approval-error-app-needs-permission-to-access-resources)